# Data disappearing with Scatter plot

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

When I zoom into a scatter plot, then at some point the data disappears.
Don't zoom in too fast, one mouse-wheel step at a time.
If you go to the center of the plot and zoom in, then after 5-6 steps the issue is apparent.

```
export default function App() {
  const options = {
    animation: false, // disabled for performance
    parsing: false, // disabled for performance
    normalized: true,

    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,

    scales: {
      x: { type: "linear", min: 0, max: 1 },
      y: { type: "linear", min: 0, max: 1 }
    },

    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        zoom: {
          wheel: { enabled: true },
          mode: "xy"
        },
        pan: { enabled: true },
        limits: {
          x: { min: 0, max: 1 },
          y: { min: 0, max: 1 }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const generateData = (num) => {
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
      data.push({ x: Math.random(), y: Math.random() });
    }
    return data;
  };

  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        type: "scatter",
        data: generateData(10000),
        backgroundColor: "#0000004D",
        pointRadius: 2,
        pointStyle: "rect",
        borderWidth: 0,
        hitRadius: 1, // extra radius added to point radius for hit detection
        hoverRadius: 0,
        hoverBorderWidth: 0 // stroke width when hovered
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <Chart options={options} data={data} />
  );
}
```

I have recreated the issue with the packages: react-chartjs-2 v5.2.0, chart.js v4.2.1 and
chartjs-plugin-zoom v2.0.1.

A sandbox with the issue can be found at: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-microservice-stlwl6

Any ideas what might be causing it?